# The type of an expression must be an array type, but it is resolved to Object

Tags: java, arrays, object

I expected this to compile, but I kept getting the error "The type of an expression must be an array type, but it is resolved to Object". Is there a simple workaround for this?

```
public class NodeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Object[] arr = new Object[5]; // each element of object will be an array of integers.
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        int[][] a = new int[2*(i+1)][2*(i+1)];
        arr[i] = a;
    }
    arr[0][0][0] = 0; //error here
}
```

}

Comment: why are you trying to hold an `int[][]` array in an `Object[]` array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`arr` is `Object[]` so `arr[0]` will return an `Object`

But since you know that `arr` contains `int[][]` as instance of `Object` you will have to cast them to be so.

```
( ( int[][] ) arr[0] )[0][0] = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to declare `arr` as `int[][][]` rather than `Object[]`. While arrays are of type `Object` so the assignment in the loop is legal, you're then losing that type information so the compiler doesn't know the elements of `arr` are `int[][]` in the bottom line.

```
int[][][] arr = new int[5][][];
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { //good practice not to hardcode 5
    arr[i] = new int[2*(i+1)][2*(i+1)];
}
arr[0][0][0] = 0; //compiles
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest think from the logic perspective rather than work around.

You are trying to use multidimensional arrays , your looping is in a single dimension{which might be right as per your requirements}. Can you post the pseudo code, this might help

This also works

```
public class NodeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] arr = new Object[5]; // each element of object will be an array
                                        // of integers.
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            int[][] a = new int[2 * (i + 1)][2 * (i + 1)];
            arr[i] = a;
        }
        arr[0] = 0; // Make it one dimensional
    }
}
```