# Constructors for arrays in Java

Tags: java

I am working on a problem where I need to have a class that is represented by a boolean array. This is the only constructor I have.

```
private boolean[] integerSet;
private static final int ARRAY_LENGTH = 101; // set will always be 0-100

// no argument constructor
// creates set filled with default value false
public Exercise_8_13()
{
    integerSet = new boolean[ARRAY_LENGTH];
}
```

The methods I am writing after this all give the error "The type of an expression must be an array type, but it is resolved to Exercise_8_13". The methods are taking arguments of type Exercise_8_13.

Do I need to make another type of constructor to prevent the error? Or is it something in the constructor I have? The question only specified that a no-argument constructor had to be created.

I have looked at this question which seems to be a similar problem but I still do not understand the solution.
[The type of an expression must be an array type, but it is resolved to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369503/the-type-of-an-expression-must-be-an-array-type-but-it-is-resolved-to-object)

Here is an example method, the error is triggered on a[counter], b[counter], and both instances of intersectionSet[counter].

```
    public static void intersection(Exercise_8_13 a, Exercise_8_13 b)
    {
            Exercise_8_13 intersectionSet = new Exercise_8_13();
            for (int counter = 0; counter < ARRAY_LENGTH; counter++)
            {
                    if ((a[counter] = false) || (b[counter = false]))
                    {
                    intersectionSet[counter] = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    intersectionSet[counter] = true;
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Show us the method you're talking about...

Comment: The methods I am writing after this all give the error "The type of an expression must be an array type <<< post at least 1 method, where u get this error

Comment: I added the method. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are treating `a` like a `boolean` array by writing `a[counter]`, even though `a` is of type `Exercise_8_13`, and not of type `boolean[]`. You are doing the same with `b` and `intersectionSet`.

You want to check `integerSet[counter]` in `a`, so change `a[counter]` to `a.integerSet[counter]`.

Do the same with `b[counter]` and `intersectionSet[counter]`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear as to why you are getting the error but I have tried to run my version of the code and it works fine. Firstly the constructor runs only when an instance of a class is created. Hence if you create an instance of the same in the main method and check for the length of the array. Here is the code that runs fine.

```
public class Exercise_8_13{

private static boolean[] integerSet ;   
private static final int ARRAY_LENGTH = 101;

public Exercise_8_13()
{
    integerSet =new boolean[ARRAY_LENGTH];
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Exercise_8_13 z = new Exercise_8_13();//new instance being created
    if(integerSet!=null)
    {
        System.out.println("Success " +integerSet.length);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is fine.  Your error indicates a mismatch between an expected type and one you're trying to either accept or return in one of the methods.  It would be easily spotted if you shared one of the methods that's presenting the error condition.

For example, if you have a method that looks like this one, then your compiler will recognize the mismatch between the stated return type (Exercise_8_13) and the actual return type (boolean[]).

```
public Exercise_8_13 copy() {
    return this.integerSet;  // deliberate bug
}
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, the name "integerSet" is kind of unusual for something describing an array of boolean values.